# error implementing strstr() function

Tags: c

I  have implemented strstr() but the code has is not working please help:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
char* mystrstr(char*,char*);
int main()
{
    char *s1,*s2,*flag;
    printf("Enter a string:\n ");
    gets(s1);
    printf("Enter a word to find in it:\n");
    gets(s2);
    flag=mystrstr(s1,s2);
    if(flag)
        printf("Word found\n");
    else
        printf("Word not found");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
char* mystrstr(char* s1,char* s2)
{       int flag=0,j,i;
    char* temp;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(s1);i++)
     {  if(*(s1+1)==s2[0])
        {
            for(j=1;*s2;j++)
            {
            if(*(s1+i)==*(s2+j))
            flag=1;
            else
            flag=0;
            }
        }
     }
     if(flag)
     {
     temp=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
     itoa(j,temp,10);
     return *temp;
     }
     return 0;


}
```

Comment: what problem are you facing?Is it not working the way you want?

Comment: very bad code, consider studying.

Comment: What you have written is not strstr but i get the intent. Break the problem into steps.

Comment: I think You cal that as a function but where you declare your function  in the program

Comment: from code it looks like you are trying to find the substring s1 in string s2 then i don't think your logic of internal loop is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Some quick tips:

1. Allocate [memory](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/malloc/) to pointers or use [arrays](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/)
2. Read more on [pointer arithmetic](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10b.html) here
3. Read about [strstr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strstr) and think of an algorithm to do so or google
4. More on [itoa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/), specifically read the [return value](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/).

Answer (score 3):

For starters, you might want to read on how 'gets' works:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gets

You're just declaring pointers on the stack in your main-method. These pointers will probably point to some random memory. As mentioned in the comments above you will have to allocate memory either on the heap using 'malloc' (`s1 = malloc(256);`) or on the stack with f.ex. '`char s1[256];`' etc. and then passing the address to it to gets with '`gets(&s1);`' instead

Comment: What I meant was that you'll have to use gets(&s1); if you're allocating memory on the stack with 'char s1[256]'. Not when using pointer and malloc, then you're correct

Comment: No. this has nothing to do with stack vs malloced memory. gets(&foo); is wrong if it's a char foo[32]; and it's wrong when it's a char *foo = malloc(32);

Comment: Sorry about that! you're correct. Guess you'll have to write gets(&s1[0]) if you want a similar effect =)

Answer (score 1):

conio.h is not ANSI C

getch is not ANSI C

itoa is not ANSI C

Your function returns a string contains a positionnumber in s2. Is this right for you?

The return must be freed.

Do you know an array-access? Better than `*(s2+j)` is `s2[j]`.

`if(*(s1+1)==s2[0])` should be `if(*(s1+i)==s2[0])` or not?

`for(j=1;*s2;j++)` should be `for(j=1;s2[j];j++)` or not?

In the case `flag=0` a break is missing, see other answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i<strlen(s1);i++)
 {  

        for(j=0;strlen(s2);j++)//and here
        {
        if(*(s1+i+j)==*(s2+j)){//here
        flag=1;}
        else{
        flag=0;break}
        }
 if(flag){break;}

 }
```

Comment: Correct me if i did something wrong because I didn't hear about c very much.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check for the first characters?

```
if(*(s1+1)==s2[0]) // you are checking s1[1] against s2[0]
```

This is infinite loop unless s2[0] is a null character in the first place or you break from the loop using break;

```
for(j=1;*s2;j++)
```

A recrusive approach for your reference:

```
char* my_strstr(char* s1, char* s2) {
  // return null pointer for empty strings
  if (strlen(s1) == 0 || strlen(s2) == 0)
    return 0;

  // recursive part
  if (s1[0] == s2[0]) {
    if (strlen(s2+1) == 0 || (strlen(s2+1) != 0 && my_strstr(s1+1, s2+1) == s1+1))
      return s1;
  }
  else return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesnt seem to work my friend.Its not finding the string.

Answer (score 0):

Java code to implement strstr()

```
class Solution {
public int strStr(String haystack, String needle) {
    String res ="";
    int pos = 0;
    if(needle.length() == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(haystack.equals(needle)){
        return 0;
    }
    if (needle.length()>haystack.length()||haystack.length() == 0){
        return -1;
    }
    for(int i =0; i<haystack.length();i++){
            if(haystack.charAt(i) == needle.charAt(0)){
                if(i+needle.length() <= haystack.length()){
                res = haystack.substring(i,i+(needle.length()));
                if (res.equals(needle)){
                pos = i;
                return pos;
                }
        }
                else{
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            else{
                continue;
            }
        }
        return -1;

}
}
```